# Google Maps API v3 Marker not being displayed

Tags: drupal, google-maps-api-3, markers

I've been searching for hours but cannot find a solution.  My marker code is very simple (grabbed from the api documentation) but I cannot seem to get the marker to show up on my website. Map itself renders fine (key is included in actual code) but with no marker.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Site: http://ath-uterwinctr.its.utexas.edu/about/location

Code in file (gmap.js) referenced by website:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(30.27639, -97.732422);
var myOptions = {
    center: myLatLng,
    zoom: 16,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-erwincenter"),
        myOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: "Frank Erwin Center"
    });
});
```

Website Code referencing gmap.js:

```
<?php
drupal_add_js('sites/all/themes/delphic/js/gmap.js');
drupal_set_html_head('<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>'); ?>

<div id="map-frame"><div id="map-erwincenter">&nbsp;</div></div>
```

Comment: Do you get any js error?

Comment: I'm using a default Google embed, and it's not appearing for me either. Google Maps viewed directly is also faulty in this way at present. It would appear that the error is at Google's end.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa Drupal never displayed one.  Not sure where to look other than one appearing on the interface.

Comment: @mcook Any articles or updates about google fixing it?  Seems like tons of people can use v3 maps with markers but me. =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your live source, you need to remove the line `marker.setMap()`. The marker will already place itself in your map with the `map: map` property defined above.

Calling `setMap` would have to be done as `marker.setMap(map)`, but it is redundant and unnecessary because of `map: map` being in the options. I think what's happening right now is `setMap()` is interpreted as `setMap(null)` and the effect is removing your marker.

http://ath-uterwinctr.its.utexas.edu/sites/default/files/js/js_40f5a94093acf14755eb100d58a7a838.js

**Line 1245**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(30.27639, -97.732422);
    var myOptions = {
        center: myLatLng,
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-erwincenter"),
            myOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: "Frank Erwin Center"
    });
    marker.setMap();  // <-- *** This line should disappear ***
});
```

Comment: I tried removing the marker.setMap() line and still no marker will appear on the map.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe your browser has cached the JavaScript source? Try clearing the cache or using another browser to test. I just loaded your page now http://ath-uterwinctr.its.utexas.edu/about/location and I see a standard marker over "Erwin Special Events Center"

Comment: I cleared the drupal cache after having removed the line and the marker finally appeared.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! Please take a few seconds to accept my answer by clicking on the big check mark outline and satisfy my greed! >:D